# I got this error when i restart the tomcat "Context initialization failed"

Tags: java, spring

I got this error when i restart the tomcat "Context initialization failed"

```
[ERROR][2013-02-26 15:48:49,432][ContextLoader] - [Context initialization failed]
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration            problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location  [applications\applications.xml]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/context/appContext.xml];  nested exception is  org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration  problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [..\..\..\..\schema\ab- products\common\resources\appContext-services.xml]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/context/applications/applications.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/schema/ab-products/common/resources/appContext-services.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/schema/ab-products/common/resources/appContext-services.xml]
```

Here is appContext-services.xml,it exists in /schema/ab-products/common/resources/appContext-services.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd">

<!-- ========================= Start of SERVICE DEFINITIONS ========================= -->

<!--
    Per-activity configuration bean.
-->
<bean id="AbCommonResources-configuration"
    class="com.archibus.service.cost.Configuration">
    <property name="defaultDateStart" value="1980-01-01" />
    <property name="defaultDateEnd" value="2099-12-31" />
</bean>

<!-- 
    Remote version of CostService. This service is not used when the client calls WFRs. 
    TODO: fix proxyInterfaces="com.archibus.utility.Immutable": define and use ICostService interface.
-->
<bean id="CostService-remote"
    class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean"
    p:proxyInterfaces="com.archibus.utility.Immutable"
    p:target-ref="CostService">
    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
            <value>securityInterceptor</value>
            <value>exceptionHandlingInterceptor</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- 
    Local version of CostService, used by WFRs. 
-->
<bean id="CostService"
    class="com.archibus.service.cost.CostService"
    scope="prototype"
    p:configuration-ref="AbCommonResources-configuration">
</bean>

<!--
    Cost beans.
-->
<bean id="actualCost"
    class="com.archibus.app.common.finance.domain.ActualCost"
    scope="prototype">
</bean>
<bean id="scheduledCost"
    class="com.archibus.app.common.finance.domain.ScheduledCost"
    scope="prototype">
</bean>
<bean id="recurringCost"
    class="com.archibus.app.common.finance.domain.RecurringCost"
    p:configuration-ref="AbCommonResources-configuration"
    scope="prototype">
</bean>
```

here is applications.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd">

<import resource="..\..\..\..\schema\ab-products\common\resources\appContext-services.xml" />
```

Comment: can u show appContext-services.xml.I think that might be the problem

Answer (score 1):

thank you for your response, i solve this issue. It s about to java version. I changed my java version 1.4 to 1.6 so now there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Goodness - here's your problem:

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/schema/ab-products/common/resources/appContext-services.xml]
```

Spring couldn't find that app context XML in the CLASSPATH.

Check the location and the way you've declared it in the web.xml.  One or both are wrong.

Comment: "seems"?  Tomcat disagrees with you.  I'd just have the servlet context loader listener load those app context XMLs.

Answer (score 0):

the problem might be the  your xml file location

FileNotFoundException means it is unable to find the file in that path.

Answer (score 0):

The stack error is pretty clear .
Context initialization fails when it loads the 
`/WEB-INF/config/context/applications/applications.xml`

I gues you import following file , 
`/schema/ab-products/common/resources/appContext-services.xml`

move the file to 
`/WEB-INF/config/context/applications/` and update you import statement in `applications.xml`

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be:

```
nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/schema/ab-products/common/resources/appContext-services.xml] at
```

Is `appContext-services.xml` present in the specified location, and readable (ie has the right permissions)?